# JavaFX Tree - Veto selection change

Tags: treeview, javafx-2

I would like to be able to "veto" a selection change on a tree. I'd like to pop-up a dialog warning the user to save before the change. How do I do this with JavaFX TreeView?

I've tried to figure out how to swap out the SelectionModel but w/o luck, because I want to use a SingleSelectionModel, but there's no setter (on TreeView) to do so.

Comment: I'm not considering this closed, as I have yet to implement a good subclass of MultiSelectionModel. There is one in the JavaFX source code as an inner TreeView, but its very custom and overly complicated (i think). Wishing there was a SimpleMultipleSelectionModel to extend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good example of how to pull this off in the Scene Builder source code. Essentially listen to a tree change. If you don't like the "proposed change", or need to pop-up a dialog box, do so. If the change isn't appropriate, then stop listening for changes, make the change, and re-listen.

Comment: This doesn't solve my related issue of handling drag events. Ideally, I'd be able to have TreeView make the selection change on "mouse up", but I may be able to finagle this Vetoable class to capture mouse events, and handle appropriately.